# C++ Cannot call function with stack template

Tags: c++, function, sorting, templates, stack

Please tell me what could be the problem. I have 2 of my own stack classes (stackm and stackl), and stack sort function:

```
template <class TStack>
void quick_sort_stack(TStack &s, TStack L, TStack G, TStack E) {
// Sort stack
}
```

To sort my arrays I call the functions:

```
template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stackm<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stackm<T>(s.size()), stackm<T>(s.size()), stackm<T>(s.size()));
}

template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stackl<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stackl<T>(), stackl<T>(), stackl<T>());
}
```

And it works. But when I try to do the same with std::stack

```
template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(std::stack<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, std::stack<T>(), std::stack<T>(), std::stack<T>());
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
(no matching function for call to quick_sort_stack(std::stack<int> &, std::stack<int>, std::stack<int>, std::stack<int>)):
```

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: And what happens when you re-order the function templates? Did you try putting the implementation function above the wrappers?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @storyteller-unslander-monica Yes, it actually worked. It's strange though, because they were all above the main sorting function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, C++ is very particular about name lookup. So usually, things aren't visible unless they are declared prior to the first point of use.

Comment: It was just weird that the rest of the options work, despite the fact that they are above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a structure like this:

```
template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stackm<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stackm<T>(s.size()), stackm<T>(s.size()), stackm<T>(s.size()));
}

template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stackl<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stackl<T>(), stackl<T>(), stackl<T>());
}

template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stack<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stack<T>(), stack<T>(), stack<T>());
}

template <class TStack>
void quick_sort_stack(TStack &s, TStack L, TStack G, TStack E) {
    // Sorted function
}
```

The program start after moving the sorting function over the rest:

```
template <class TStack>
void quick_sort_stack(TStack &s, TStack L, TStack G, TStack E) {
    // Sorted function
}

template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stack(stackl<T> &s) {
    quick_sort_stack(s, stackl<T>(), stackl<T>(), stackl<T>());
}
// Another...
```

Comment: Reason it works for your classes `stackl`/`stackm` is because they are in the same namespace that your `quick_sort_stack(TStack &s, TStack L, TStack G, TStack E)` function. Look at [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have explicitly indicated the use of std::stack at the beginning of the file: using std::stack;

Comment: So you can use `stack` without spelling `std::stack`, but `foo(stack())` still search `foo` in previous declaration  for current namespace and namespace `std`. I just want to explain quickly your ADL issue.